# Can't get spring-security.xml right

Tags: java, spring-security, javabeans, servlet-filters

I have my spring security set up to do basic authentication to a database with no issues, however I would like to add custom login/logout and admin pages as well as md5 encryption on passwords w/ salt.

I keep hitting walls trying to get either of these features to work, and all the examples online seem to be using  and declaring  like that instead of using bean declarations like I am. This makes it more difficult because options in examples don't seem to directly translate into bean properties.

Here is my web.xml - I am using Spring Security 3.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        /WEB-INF/builder-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/builder-service.xml
        /WEB-INF/builder-data.xml
        /WEB-INF/builder-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>builder</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>builder</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.docx</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>targetClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And here is my builder-security (mind the disorganization):

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<!--<s:authentication-manager>
    <s:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</s:authentication-manager>-->

<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <s:filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
        <s:filter-chain pattern="/**"
            filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter,
                    exceptionTranslationFilter,
                    authenticationProcessingFilter,
                    filterSecurityInterceptor,
                    anonymousAuthenticationFilter"/>
    </s:filter-chain-map>
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter"/>

<bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
    <property name="providers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="authenticationProvider"/>
            <ref bean="anonymousAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <!--<property name="passwordEncoder" ref="md5PasswordEncoder"/>-->
    <!--<property name="saltSource" ref="systemWideSaltSource"/>-->
    <property name="userDetailsService" ref="authenticationDao"/>
    <property name="userCache" ref="userCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="md5PasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder">

</bean>

<bean id="systemWideSaltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.SystemWideSaltSource">
    <property name="systemWideSalt" value="XXXX"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userCache" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.cache.EhCacheBasedUserCache">
    <property name="cache" ref="ehcache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheFactoryBean">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="cacheName" value="userCache"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationDao" class="org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>

<!--<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="realmName" value="SpecBuilder"/>
</bean>-->
<bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="voter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="voter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
    <property name="userAttribute" value="anonymousUser,ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
</bean>

<bean id="anonymousAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="key" value="foobar"/>
</bean>

<bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
    <property name="objectDefinitionSource">
        <s:filter-invocation-definition-source>
            <s:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS"/>
            <s:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/> <!-- isAuthenticated() probably better -->
        </s:filter-invocation-definition-source>
    </property>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Right now I am trying to get login.html to all anonymous access, yet all I get is an infinite security loop.

Is there a reason I shouldn't be using bean declarations for this? Because not very many people seem to be doing so. I'd rather not change the whole thing if there is no advantage to doing it. There has to be something wrong with it or a better place to go to get bean declaration references and examples, because most all searches turn up the other style of implementing spring security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fair bit of research and testing, I've solved it.
The built in security namespace does a good chunk of the work for you. Creating each filter and manager bean by bean is a good way to customize things, but it makes it quite bit more difficult and it's not really necessary.

My final code involves a custom user class that includes a salt value and a custom dao class to enforce the use of the salt.  Everything else is done through use of the security namespace.

builder-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:s="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<s:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
    <s:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER') or hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <s:form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
    <s:logout logout-url="/logout"/>
</s:http>

<s:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <s:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <s:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <s:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </s:password-encoder>            
    </s:authentication-provider>
</s:authentication-manager>

<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" id="saltSource">
    <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt"/>
</bean>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="builder.webapp.security.CustomJdbcDaoImpl">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="enableAuthorities" value="true"/>
    <property name="enableGroups" value="false"/>
    <property name="usersByUsernameQuery"
              value="select username,password,enabled,salt from users where username = ?"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step spring security explained:

http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-set-up-and.html

Good luck!